# Spring cloud stream custom binder not registered. Disables the kafka binder if used @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to make a custom spring cloud stream binder but it just wont register itself:

Binder Implementation:

```
public class DPSBinder implements Binder<SubscribableChannel, ConsumerProperties, ProducerProperties> {

private DecisionPersistenceServiceClient dpsClient;

private MessageHandler dpsClientConsumerMessageHandler = null;

public DPSBinder(DecisionPersistenceServiceClient dpsClient) {
    this.dpsClient = dpsClient;
}

@Override
public Binding<SubscribableChannel> bindConsumer(String name, String group, SubscribableChannel inboundBindTarget,
        ConsumerProperties consumerProperties) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public Binding<SubscribableChannel> bindProducer(String name, SubscribableChannel outboundBindTarget,
        ProducerProperties producerProperties) {

    switch (name) {

    case "PERSIST_POST":

        this.dpsClientConsumerMessageHandler = message -> dpsClient.persist((DPAPayload) message.getPayload());

        break;

    default:
        this.dpsClientConsumerMessageHandler = null;

    }

    if (this.dpsClientConsumerMessageHandler != null)
        this.subscribe(outboundBindTarget);

    return () -> this.dpsClientConsumerMessageHandler = null;

}

public void subscribe(SubscribableChannel outboundBindTarget) {

    outboundBindTarget.subscribe(this.dpsClientConsumerMessageHandler);
}}
```

configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class DPSBinderConfiguration {
@Bean
public DPSBinder dpsBinder(DecisionPersistenceServiceClient dpsClient) {

    return new DPSBinder(dpsClient);
}}
```

spring.binders file:

```
dps:something.something.DPSBinderConfiguration
```

application.yml

```
application.yml
spring:
 cloud:
  stream:
   bindings:
    input:
      destination: DPP_EVENTS
      group: dpp-local
      binder: kafka
    output:
      destination: PERSIST_POST
      binder: dps
  binders:
    kafka:
      type: kafka
    dps:
      type: dps
```

I've followed the spring cloud stream guidelines for creating a custome binder but this is not working. Moreover, using the @Configuration for creating binder beans disables the kafka binder which i've added on classpath.

Comment: Creating binders is not a straight forward topic, so first I wonder what guidelines have you followed? Also, for such complex question it is recommended that you post your project on GitHub or somewhere when one of use can look, reproduce etc.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky: I noticed you are part of the Spring team, are there guidelines/best practices for implementing a custom binder? In section 4.2 of the SCS documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-binder-abstraction), it mentions a custom binder can be implemented by using "the extensible API to write your own Binder", but it's not abundantly clear on where to start

Comment: We will be publishing a guide on how to implement a custom binder, but unfortunately it is not available at the moment. That said, you can see the [partner implementations](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#overview) together with ours and it should not be hard to follow.

Comment: can you share your code in github

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Actually @Configuration should not be used where the binding bean is being declared.
Also, there were some logical issues in My binder implementation which i fixed.